# Double Torus Parametric Surface

Tags: gn.general-topology, at.algebraic-topology

In the process of trying to find continuous parametric surface equations for the double torus and for a pair of pants, I believe that the problem is unsolvable for some topological reason.

I have found a few arguments for why you can't do it using various approaches, in which it would force a discontinuity, but I would like a solid proof of this.

The main reason this is important is because it would be quite useful to have a continuous parametrization for such a surface.

Alternatively, might I be wrong and could there actually exist continuous parametrizations for such surfaces?

Comment: I was wondering if you could define your terms more precisely.
By "double torus" I'm guessing you mean a genus two (2-holed) surface.
But what exactly do you mean by "continuous parameterization"?
There is, in fact, a continuous map from the disk to a genus two surface.

Comment: Instead of  "to a genus..." I should have said "onto a ..." in my last sentence.

Comment: On the other hand, there is no *bijective* continuous function from a disk to either a pair of pants or a genus-two surface. 

Comment: (By the way, math.stackexchange.com might have been a better place to ask this question)

Comment: There is a bijective parametrization of the pair of pants by a disc with two holes cut out.  I agree with Mariano that your question is not quite appropriate for this web site.  Please see the FAQ for a list of sites where you may find more complete answers.